# Responsive table with fixed first column and header

Tags: html, css, responsive, tabular

This must be something similar to Excel table, where header and first column are fixed with width saving when content in content cells are different heights.

Requirements:

1. First column fixed to left side, can move only vertically
2. Table header fixed to top, can move only horizontally

Have some code with divs table:
[Div table](https://fiddle.jshell.net/68erzhcq/)

and table tag table
[Table tag table](https://fiddle.jshell.net/y4aqxcug/)

and nothing's working properly.
Need help with it.